# Laravel: How to insert an item in Select which is pre populated with records?

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I am using Laravel 5.1. In form I am generating drop down as:

```
{!! Form::select('ptype', $p_types,null,['class' => 'form-control text-capitalize']) !!}
```

While in controller `$p_types` is set as:

```
$p_types = PType::lists('name', 'id');
```

I want to show an option as `Select here` on top of drop down. How do I do tat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple solution to doing what you're asking, as mentioned here. [Form:recipes add placeholder attribute](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/163/creating-a-select-box-field) What you can do is in the lists method insert a record into the collection before it's passed to the blade template. Checkout this link [Collection Methods](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-push). That is by far the easiest solution.

```
$p_types->push("Select Here");
```

Comment: Correct Collection outputs values like:

 #items: array:8 [▼
    1 => "website"    
  ]

Comment: `$p_types->prepend('Choose Project Type',0);` this worked like charm. Thanks!

Comment: To get it into the front you could do `$collection = $collection->splice(count($p_types), 0, "Select Here");` Which will put it into the front of the collection, then you could just mark this as the selected item when iterating it over.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this in blade template to add the `Select here` option on top of drop down

```
{!! Form::select('ptype',([''=>'Select here']+$p_types->toArray()) ,null,['class' => 'form-control text-capitalize']) !!}
```